# In-universe origin of the Ring poem

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

> Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,
>   Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,
>   Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,
>   One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne
>   In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.
>   One Ring to rule them all. One Ring to find them,
>   One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them
>   In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

In-universe, who composed this, and when?

It should be Sauron, since the poem is on the One Ring. But at the time of its forging, the "lesser" rings had not yet been given to the Men and Dwarves (since Sauron himself gave it to them after retrieving them from the elves of Eregion).

Comment: Yep, thanks ! Should I delete my question ?

Comment: Deleting your question isn't necessary. It's useful to have different wordings of the question title for what is essentially the same question so people can find the answer they're looking for more easily.